# Scheduling a task with intervals-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to implement falling leaves in my game in particular intervals.
After 10 seconds of game starts,leaves has to fall.Then again leaves has to fall after 20 seconds and so on.

I have this method for the falling leaves of array;

```java
private void updateFalls(float delta) {
    for (Leaf l : leaves) {
        l.moveLeavesDown(delta);
    }
    spawnleaves();
}
```

Is it possible to do with timer class?Is it possible to call this method inside timer with fixed intervals?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Timer in this way :

```java
Timer timer=new Timer();
timer.scheduleTask(new Timer.Task() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        spawnLeaf();
    }
},10,20);            //  -->  10 is your first delay and 20 is interval in sec.
```

I'm considering Leaf as a `Sprite` but it may be an `Image` or any other `Entity`.

Here is my `spawnLeaf` method :

```java
Array<Sprite> leaves=new Array<Sprite>();
private void spawnLeaf(){
    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture);

    sprite.setPosition(MathUtils.random(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    leaves.add(sprite);
}
```

Draw and position update part of all leaves

```java
spriteBatch.begin();

Iterator<Sprite> iter = leaves.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Sprite spr = iter.next();
    spr.draw(spriteBatch);
    spr.setY(spr.getY()-50f*Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    if (spr.getY()<0) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
spriteBatch.end();
```

`Timer` has `clear()` and `stop()` method that help in removing all scheduled tasks and stops the timer respectively that may start again.